# Expressão regular em PHP

Tags: php, array, string

Boa noite, estou precisando receber uma string via POST, e quebrá-la em palavras-chave, porém é possível que o usuário separe as palavras de três formas: com vírgula(','), espaço vazio(' ') ou vírgula seguida de espaço vazio(', ').
Estou pensando em utilizar o método *split()*, visto que um de seus parâmetros é uma expressão regular.
Minha pergunta é: como seria uma expressão regular que considerasse essas condições? (vírgula OU espaço vazio OU vírgula seguida de espaço vazio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra isso você deve utilizar o [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-split.php), exemplo:

```
$palavras = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $_POST["string"]);

// reparte a frase quando encontrar espaço (\s), vírgula ou os dois
```